# New to AWS Lambda - configure function to run only on both triggers being executed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am new to developing with AWS Lambda. I have my function running correctly, but I wanted to modify it to run only when both triggers are triggered, perhaps within a certain timeframe (e.g. trigger 1 is hit, if trigger 2 is hit within a few seconds only then execute the Lambda function).

I am struggling to find a feasible way to do this - would I rely on CloudWatch logs, or is there an easier way to do this in AWS Lambda console?

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of triggers are you talking about? Maybe we can find a smarter solution.

Comment: @MaiKaY It is currently an AWS IoT button and API Gateway call that are triggering the Lambda function. The API Gateway call is emanating from a lower power microcontroller - we would like to find a way for the function to run only when both occur.

Comment: What if I press, press, press (3 times) the button and then the API gateway  is called within your set time treshold, do you want to trigger it three times as well?

Comment: Possible option to investigate: set up your lambda as a stream function that checks for recent dynamo records created just before the currently-processing record. If one exists, do the thing, otherwise do nothing. This would require you to setup another lambda to actually write records to dynamo (with a creation time).

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but I guess that [step function](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) could help you.

When you creating state machine of the step function, you could choose  *Sample Projects (2-10 minutes)/Job Status Poller*. This sample has similar workflow if I get correct your question.

[image]

I don't know all details of your problem, but step function looks good solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to create a DynamoDB table (super cheap) to maintain the state using Epoch Time in milliseconds, Event Name, ExpirationTime in (Epoch Seconds), and some identifying key.

The key in the DynamoDB table would depend on what you're trying to accomplish.  If it is a one to one relationship between IoT Button push and the API Gateway Trigger you could use a key of "ItDoesntMatter" and simply update the time and event name for each event that occurs.  If the event happenned within some time frame of the last event then do something.

Here is a sample set of columns to use in the DynamoDB table:

```
Key
EventName
LastEpochTimeInMs
ExpirationTimeInSeconds (optional)
```

Here is some pseudocode for a Lambda Function:
Input({"SourceEvent": "Button" or "ApiGateway"})

```
var oldRecord = PutItemIntoDynamoDbWithReturnValueALL_OLD(input);  //Not sure how atomic this is though...
var millisecondsRangeToAcceptForAction = GetEvironmentVariable("TimeRangeToAcceptForActionInMs"); // i.e. 2000 for 2seconds

var isNewRecord = (oldRecord is null);
var isSameEventTwiceInaRow = (oldRecord.EventName == input["SourceEvent"]);

if(isNewRecord || isSameEventTwiceInaRow) { 
    return;
}
else if(oldRecord.LastEpochTimeInMs > currentEpochTimeInMs - millisecondsRangeToAcceptForAction)
    DoSomethingImportantNowThatBothEventsHaveTakenPlaceInCloseEnoughProximityToOneAnother(input);
}
```

Just a quick example that could be reworked any number of ways.  To productionize it you'd need to figure out concurrency, atomicity, etc.